# how can I find what function a key combo is mapped to?

Tags: vim, neovim

I have some key mappings that are colliding. How can I figure out what my key combo is maping to?

I've tried the following:

```
:map <C-h>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

typing the following will tell us what file contains a mapping to Ctrl + h key combo:

```
:verbose map <C-h>
```